# Http 404 error is getting when static page is deployed

Tags: java, html, http

I created a web project using Eclipse. I added one html page index.html inside the WebContent folder. I deployed the project using tomcat 7.  When try to run on the server it is giving 404 resource not found error

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Simple Servlet</title>`
</head>
<body>
Hey I am creating simple HTML Page!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What URL are you using to access the page?

Comment: Your HTML is clearly not the problem.  Are you deploying as a war?  What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help.Now my html is running fine.i did n't see any error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hot deployment in eclipse, right click on the the html and say run on server, select the server, eclipse should open the html with the correct URL on web browser within eclipse